# Bootstrap 4: Fixed position sidebar overlapped by the content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Long story short: I'm building a website using SB Admin 2 template with some minor modifications and one of the things I want to change is making the left sidebar fixed so it stays in place while scrolling. Adding .position-fixed to the main UL wrapper does just that but at the same time it causes #content-wrapper div, which immediately follows the UL, to span the entire width of the page and overlap the sidebar. I've played with margin-left value for the #content-wrapper but it's too dependent on screen resolution. Plus, I want the content wrapper to expand when the sidebar is collapsed, just like it does in vanilla SB Admin 2. Any tips are appreciated. Sidebar and content wrapper classes are currently as follows:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-secondary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion position-fixed" id="accordionSidebar">

<div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine. Solved it myself by adding #wrapper #content-wrapper {margin-left: 14rem;} to CSS and writing this bit of jQuery for the sidebar collapse button. Seems to work flawlessly across all resolutions:

```
    $('#sidebarToggle').click( function(e) {
      if ($("#accordionSidebar").hasClass("toggled")) {
       $('#content-wrapper').css({'margin-left': "6.5rem"});
     } else {
       $('#content-wrapper').css({'margin-left': "14rem"});
     }
    });
```